# Restrict access to a sub-folder while sharing access to a folder

Tags: google-drive

I have a Google Drive folder that I want to share with 2 more people. However I would like to restrict one the folders. So let's say we have John and Josh, how can I can I share the whole google drive folder with John and Josh and only a sub-folder within the drive with Josh?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to share the whole drive (larger directory/folder) with both of them, then remove Josh from the sub-directory specifically.

#### Instructions:

1. Share the larger directory with both of them.
2. Navigate to the parent directory of the sub-directory you don't want to share with Josh.
3. Select the sub-directory you want to hide from Josh.
4. Click the "Share *directory name*" button (the person icon with the plus sign) *or* right click then click "Share".
5. Click "Shared with John and Josh" (under where you can invite people to the directory).
6. Click the "X" by Josh's name.

I tested this approach and it worked well!

Comment: Won't Josh still have access to those files for a small amount of time? Would Josh be able to recover those files because he did have access to them?

Comment: Yes, Josh would have access for as long as it takes you to remove him from sub directories plus the time it takes to propogate through the system. Josh should not be to recover those files in the future

Comment: Can any Manager make these changes? I can add and remove members in the parent directory but the "Share" option is grayed out in the sub-directory.

Comment: @BrianDTiessen I'm not sure in what powers a "Manager" has or doesn't have, sorry