# Restrict access to a sub-folder while sharing access to a folder on team drive

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, google-shared-drive

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107490) was asked by Henk Straten on 5 July 2017 and answered by Zach Saucier:  I have a Google Drive folder that I want to share with 2 more people. However I would like to restrict one the folders. So let's say we have John and Josh, how can I can I share the whole google drive folder with John and Josh and only a sub-folder within the drive with Josh?

My follow up question is: Can any Manager make these changes? I can add and remove members in the parent directory but the "Share" option is grayed out in the sub-directory.

Comment: I see the issue now.  I was looking at a Team Drive and Zach's answer was for sharing a folder in Google Drive.

Comment: The above comment should be posted on the answer, as it's a follow up comment of a previous one.

Answer (score 1):

On Google Drive Team Drives it's not possible to change the sharing settings of a subfolder.

Comment: But according to Zach Saucier you can.  Check this link:  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/107490/restrict-access-to-a-sub-folder-while-sharing-access-to-a-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1